# where is the type in elasticsearch7.1 index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-1.6.0

i was using elasticsearch-1.6 here we have an index and a type and inside that type we have the documents 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-index_.html
as we had twitter as an index and tweet as an type and 1 is the document id
now i need to upgrade to elasticsearch current version which is 7.1 but in the docs the type is missing 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html

so how can i define a type in index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`types` are deprecated in ES 7.x version, According to official ES site.

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 7.0.0 or later no longer accept a
>   *default* mapping. Indices created in 6.x will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x. Types are deprecated in APIs in 7.0, with
>   breaking changes to the index creation, put mapping, get mapping, put
>   template, get template and get field mappings APIs.

read more about this breaking change [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html) .

Why its removed is explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html#_why_are_mapping_types_being_removed).

But they provide some alternative to `types` which is explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html#_alternatives_to_mapping_types)

Let me know if you need any clarification.